# Ubuntu sleep back immediately after wake up

Tags: suspend

Ubuntu sleep back immediately after wake up. I reviewed /var/log but not found anything related with this issue.

Nonetheless when cron execute suspend the machine remains up and live.

Ubuntu version: 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver).
Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: What laptop model and graphics card are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu version: 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver). Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display